# Why does this assembly program produce no output?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, openbsd

Being new to x86_64 assembly, I am trying to write a basic "hello" program on my laptop running 64-bit OpenBSD. The program runs to completion with exit code 0, but seems to ignore the system call to write text to stdout. Why?

I am using the GNU assembler and creating the executable with:

`as -o hello.o hello.s; ld -Bstatic hello.o`

```
# OpenBSD ELF identification
.section ".note.opensd.ident", "a"
.p2align 2
.long 0x8
.long 0x4
.long 0x1
.ascii "OpenBSD\0"
.long 0x0
.p2align 2

.section .data
msg: .ascii "hello"

.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    push $5 # number of bytes to write
    push $msg # message address
    push $1 # file descriptor 1 for stdout
    mov $4, %eax # write is system call 4
    syscall

    push $0 # exit code 0
    mov $1, %eax # exit is system call 1
    syscall
```

Comment: I don't know about OpenBSD, but on Linux you're supposed to pass arguments in rdi/rsi/rdx/r10/r8/r9 if you want to use `syscall`, not use the stack. [It seems to be the same on FreeBSD](https://thebrownnotebook.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/native-64-bit-hello-world-with-nasm-on-freebsd/). Maybe you're confusing syscall and int 0x80 ?

Comment: Passing parameters in registers worked. Apparently, 32-bit BSDs use the [stack](http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions) and 64-bit versions use registers. If you don't mind, what is the difference between syscall and int 0x80? As far as I have read, int 0x80 just means interrupt 80, which is used for system calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tag x86_64 and probably are on an x86_64 system. Therefore you need to:

- as --64
- use pushq instead of pushl to push 64bit values on the stack
- transfer those values to the appropriate registers before syscall

  ```
  .section ".note.opensd.ident", "a"
  .p2align 2
  .long 0x8
  .long 0x4
  .long 0x1
  .ascii "OpenBSD\0"
  .long 0x0
  .p2align 2

  .section .data
   msg: .ascii "hello"

  .section .text
  .globl _start
  _start:
          pushq $0x4
          popq %rax               # 4 (write syscall) into rax
          pushq $0x1
          popq %rdi               # 1 (STDOUT) into rdi
          pushq $msg
          popq %rsi               # address of hello msg into rsi
          pushq $0x5
          popq %rdx               # length of hello msg into rdx
          syscall
          pushq $1
          popq %rax
          pushq $0
          popq %rdi
          syscall
  ```

the following articles offer some good info:

[x64 asm on FreeBSD](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/17746/)

[differences between x86 and x64 asm](http://www.exploit-db.com/papers/13136/)

Comment: Accepted for working code, and thanks for the articles.

Comment: push $4 / pop %rax is a weird and inefficient way to write `mov $4, %eax`.  You'd normally only do things like that if you're optimizing for code size over speed, or writing shellcode that needs to avoid 00 bytes in the machine code.  And once you have one constant, you can `lea` others relative to it with a 3-byte instruction like `lea -3(%rax), %edi` if you really want to optimize for code-size over performance and readability.